# Probema con discord developper

Tags: discord.py

Hola estoy haciendo un bot de discord pero en la página de desarrolladores de discord para hacer bots no me deja seleccionar los permisos del bot una vez seleccionado la casilla bot en el OAuth
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No , no es el client_id real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución mas simple a ese problema es haciendo los siguientes pasos:

1- Copiar la Id de tu bot.

2- Ir a https://discordapi.com/permissions.html#8.

3- Seleccionar los permisos que necesites, en este caso el de administrador.

4- Pegas la id de tu bot en la casilla inferior.

5- Accedes al link y lo invitas a tu servidor.

Comment: No entiendo porque dices que esta mal formulada , es solo un problema que tengo con la plataforma de desarrollo de discord no veo que hay de mal el preguntarlo por aqui , con respecto a que esta fuera de tema tampoco tiene sentido lo que dices ya que el tema en este caso esta bien claro en las etiquetas que puse es decir puse la etiqueta de discord.py ya que estoy haciendo un bot en python y de ahi viene la pregunta , por favor si vas a decir algo en relación con la pregunta relcaciona bien los conceptos por favor ya que esta tiene todo el sentido y no se saca ningun tema a parte